# output not declaired.anyone please help me to fix this problem

Tags: arduino-uno

output not declaired.anyone please help me to fix this problem

```
int const trigpin=10;
int const echopin=9;
int const buzzpin=2;
void setup() 
{
  {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
 }
  pinmode(trigpin,output);
  pinmode(echopin,input);
  pinmode(buzzpin,output);
}
void loop() 
{
  long int duration,distance;
  digitalwrite(trigpin,high);
  delaymicroseconds(1000);
  digitalwrite(trigpin,low);
  duration=pulsein(echopin,high);
  distance=(duration/2)/29.1;
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println("CH");
  if(distance<=50)
   {
    digitalwrite(buzzpin,high);
   }
   else if(distance>50)
   {
    digitalwrite(buzzpin,low);
   }
   delay(60);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To be used in the pinMode function (note capital M), it needs to be all capitals, ie OUTPUT.

From a quick scan, you might also need the following changes:

output ==> OUTPUT

input ==> INPUT

pinmode  ==> pinMode

digitalwrite ==> digitalWrite

delaymicroseconds ==> delayMicroseconds

Make sure your code matches the case (uppercase/lowercase) of the examples/tutorials etc.